# .NET Core EF - Get logging output from a custom DbCommand

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've already my logging framework hooked up to *nearly all* of my database code via the standard `contextOptions.UseLoggerFactory(...)` method.  However, there is one piece of code where we are required to run our own, custom generated SQL via a `context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()` object.  This object apparently does *not* inherit the standard logging from the `context` object.  The rest of my EF code generates output like `Executing DbCommand...` or `Executed DbCommand (123ms)...`.  I would like for this custom command to do the same (without having to manually log that information myself.  I've looked around the DbCommand and DbConnection objects but I can't figure out how to tie into the logging for just this query.  Any ideas?

Here is the gist of the code that I'm looking at:

```
using (var cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) {
  command.CommandTest = "SELECT 1+1"; // not our real query :D
  await context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync(token);
  using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, token)) {
    ... other logic...
  }
}
```